# Allocation on self or underscore in ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Lets say I have a customView defined with strong property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *customView;
```

What would be the best practice of allocating and initializing customView ?

`self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame......`

OR

`_customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you. You can go the "always use getters and setters" route if you want to never think about it again. Or if you don't feel like wasting message calls and littering your code with `self.` (like me), you can go the "use instance variables unless I *need* to use getters/setters" route.

Answer (score 2):

Approach :: By default when you synthesize the getter and setter accessor methods it is assumed that the property and ivar have the same name.

This can make it confusing at first glance as to when you are using the getter/setter methods and when you are accessing the ivar directly.

The alternative is name the ivar differently from the property. A common approach is to use an underscore to prefix the ivars names.

You can Refer this link : [Understanding Your (Objective-C) Self](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/08/understanding-your-objective-c-self.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be

```
self.customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame......
```

Because the getters and setters for customView would only be activated if we are using that variable with self. Otherwise, there is no need to declare the property of that variable.